# SSIS Package completes successfully when ran from Visual Studio SSDT but fails from SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent, folder-permissions

So I have a SSIS package that completes successfully when ran from the SSDT/Vis Studio but fails when called from SQL Agent.

The error I receive from the SQL Agent is generic and doesnt hint what it is as below...

It just says "The package execution failed.  The step failed."

So as for what the SSIS package does...

> It makes a call to my database and grabs some records.

> It then loops through all of the records and makes an API call to another one of my websites (a small API that deals with parsing documents e.g. pdfs etc)

> The API that is called looks for a file e.g. pdf/word and parses it then saves it to the database, it can on occasion also write a new file to a folder

So my SQL Agent runs under the administration account from my server which has folder permissions to the above mentioned folder structure.

The small API also has folder permissions to the folder structure.

(Both read and write perms)

I am struggling to see what the issue is, any ideas would be great!

Comment: Does the admin account have access right to your website / to make API calls? We had a similar problem and we had to configure some proxy settings in the the source component (we used a C# script component in order to perform the API calls) ind order to work correctly.

Comment: @Tyron78 sorry what do you mean by access rights? folder permissions?

Comment: You wrote you read from a website, so I suppose you are doing a http or web request? This is where we had an issue: the admin user was not allowed to access the web. After this was fixed, we still had to provide proxy settings in order for the request to work.